# $scope.$watch not firing after jquery onchange?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

ok I can't seem to get $scope.watch to fire..

```
        $scope.amountselected = 5;

    $scope.qtyselected = 1;

    $scope.$watch(['qtyselected'], function () {
        console.log($scope.availbleprecheckout);
    });

    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        jQuery('#weight').on('change', function() {
                $scope.amountselected = parseInt(this.value);
                $scope.$digest();
        });
        jQuery('.input-text.qty').bind('change', function(){
            $scope.$apply(function(fn){
                $scope.qtyselected ='AHHHHH'; 
            });
        });
    }); 
    $scope.$watch(['qtyselected','amountselected'], function () {

            console.log('quantity:'+$scope.qtyselected);

            console.log('weight:'+$scope.amountselected);

            console.log('avail:'+$scope.availbleprecheckout);

    });
```

I've tried $scope.$apply $scope.digest, I've tried nesting the $scope.$watch inside the document ready inside the .on('change' but nothing seems to work.
Why

Comment: does change to `$scope.$watch('qtyselected', function () {}` helps?

Comment: try `$scope.$watch('qtyselected',..` and  `$scope.$watch('qtyselected,amountselected',..` instead

Comment: ok $scope.$watch('qtyselected',.. works.. but $scope.$watch('qtyselected,amountselected',.. is a syntax error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `$watch`, you should put name of watched variable as a string, not as an array of strings.

Use simply :

```
$scope.$watch('qtyselected', function(){

});
```

If you want to watch multiple variables, you can use:

```
$scope.$watchCollection('[qtyselected,amountselected]',function(){

});
```

Or

```
$scope.$watch('qtyselected+amountselected',function(){

});
```

Comment: actually   $scope.$watchCollection('[qtyselected, amountselected]', function () {
    
    console.log('quantity:'+$scope.qtyselected);

    console.log('weight:'+$scope.amountselected);
    
    console.log('avail:'+$scope.availbleprecheckout);

  }, true);

is the correct syntax. 
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2566-scope-watch-vs-watchcollection-in-angularjs.htm

SEE: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watchCollection

Comment: if you want to correct the answer I'll gladly accept it and give soem rep:D